# Simple Criteria query - Select From IN

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, criteria, criteria-api, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I have table **Events**

```
 |  EVENT_ID   |   OTHER    |
 ----------------------------
 |             |            |
 |             |            |
 |             |            |
```

and table **EventCategories** that contains foreign key for Event table:

```
 |  TABLE_ID   |  EVENT_ID  |
 ----------------------------
 |             |            |
 |             |            |
 |             |            |
```

I need all EVENT_ID that are within Events table but are not in EventCategories table.

```
    SELECT EVENT_ID FROM Events
    WHERE EVENT_ID NOT IN 
        (
          SELECT DISTINCT EVENT_ID 
          FROM EventCategories
        )
```

How can I write criteria query ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably edit your question to say what you have tried.

You want a predicate to test for Events with an empty EventCategory collection. In JPQL it would look something like this

```
select e from Event e where e.categories is empty
```